# How to remove layers i added playing AVplayer Swift

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have an app that reenter the same view bunch of times creating a layer for an mp4 video everytime, creating a memory creep because the layers aren't getting removed, or at least that is my guess. How could i remove the layers that are added?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {



     let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("info2", withExtension: "mp4")!


        mygtukas = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        mygtukas?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
        mygtukas?.muted = true



        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: mygtukas)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.zPosition = 1
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:20.0, y: 703.0, width: 36.0, height: 36.0)


        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        mygtukas?.play()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: "loopVideo",
            name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
            object:nil)




}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

Make the playerLayer a class instance and try the following.
Call inside loopVideo method:

> playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

Comment: added ur line to my deinit function but the power still is creeping up, is seems like layers are being removed but still no memory is released after i leave the view

Comment: the layers are being removed but memory creep still happens, could that be the casE?

Comment: Please share the code chunk where you are using playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer(). This will help me understand your problem better.